# Is an Apple watch app required in order to use SiriKit?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, watchos, siri

I've set up Siri on my iOS app- I am able to call intents using INAddTasksIntent and it works great.

When I say "Hey Siri, add task clean my room to JoshApp" it works great.

However, Siri does not work on my Apple watch, using the same commands.  When I say "Hey Siri, add task clean my room to JoshApp", it will say it cannot find the app or to look on the app store.

Do I need to create a separate Apple watch app and handle the Siri intents there?  Based on my research (which incidentally, there is very little documentation around it), it doesn't seem like it is possible unless you set up a watchOS app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intents are delivered to individual devices as part of app bundles:

> #### Overview
>
> Interactions with SiriKit occur through your Intents app extension, which you deliver inside your iOS or watchOS app bundle.
>
> [...]
>
> #### Enable the Siri Capability
>
> Enabling the Siri capability adds a set of entitlements to your app. The App Store requires the presence of these entitlements for any iOS app or watchOS app containing an Intents extension.
>
> [...]

<sup>Source: [Creating an Intents App Extension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/intent_handling_infrastructure/creating_an_intents_app_extension)</sup>

Without the associated app bundle being installed on the watchOS device, it's (loosely, I'll admit) implied that you won't be able to add an Intents extension to meet your requirements.